# How to set Justify-Alignment for check boxes?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside2

I have placed some `QCheckBox` in horizontal layout (or in grid layout).

[image]

The desired output is something like below (to get this output I have added some layout spacing, but it's not very precision):

[image]

I have also tried using `setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)` or `setAlignment(Qt.AlignJustify)`, neither is working rightly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to set the horizontal policy to `QSizePolicy::Maximum` in the QCheckboxes, and place spacers between them:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QTextEdit" name="textEdit"/>
    </item>
    <item>
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
      <item>
       <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Maximum" vsizetype="Fixed">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Test1</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>40</width>
          <height>20</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox_2">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Maximum" vsizetype="Fixed">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Test2</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>40</width>
          <height>20</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox_3">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Maximum" vsizetype="Fixed">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Test3</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_3">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>40</width>
          <height>20</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox_4">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Maximum" vsizetype="Fixed">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Test4</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_4">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>40</width>
          <height>20</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox_5">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Maximum" vsizetype="Fixed">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Test5</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_5">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>40</width>
          <height>20</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox_6">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Maximum" vsizetype="Fixed">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Test6</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_6">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>40</width>
          <height>20</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox_7">
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Maximum" vsizetype="Fixed">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Test7</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>30</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```